# Access overridden variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, scope

How can I access an overridden variable inside a nested function? The overridden variable is not global, it's inside an outer function itself.

```
function print() {
  var x = "one";

  function log() {
    var x = "two";
    console.log(x); // I want to print "one" from this line
  };

  log();
}
print(); // prints "two"
```

Comment: "*I want to print "one" from this line*" you cannot. You *have* to change your code so you don't shadow the same variable name. Any reason you need to use this code?

Comment: Pass `x` as an argument to `log`, and print the argument instead of the local variable.